# Triggering forward button with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, triggers, forward

Is it possible to trigger forward button on the browser by clicking an HTML element?

I have a BUTTON that if I click will lead to a NEW PAGE. 
The new page is progressive and constantly changing due to a setInterval function.

When I go back and click the BUTTON again the NEW PAGE load from the begining, of course.
But if I use forward button, the NEW PAGE appears at the state it was left before I go back.

Can I trigger the forward button by clicking the BUTTON?
I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `window.history` object. Either of these should take you a step forward:

```
window.history.forward()
```

or

```
window.history.go(1)
```